# What is the best module in perl that can implement Paros proxy functionality

Tags: perl, security, web-applications, parosproxy

Does anybody know about a good perl module that implement the most of the functionality 
of Paros proxy http://www.parosproxy.org/

If yes, please provide some modules to do that.

Answer (score 3):

[`HTTP::Proxy`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Proxy)